# To which if does given else-if belong to?

Tags: if-statement

given that x = 1, y = -1, z = 1;

```
 if (x > 0)
       if (y > 0)
          System.out.println("x > 0 and y > 0");
    else if ( y< 0)
          System.out.println("x < 0 and z > 0");
```

This code prints x < 0 and z > 0;
How is this possible?To which if does given else-if  belong to?

Comment: you are getting the correct output!!! don't look like python code for the indentation to determine the level.

Comment: Specifying language may be good idea. I suspect language you are using is Java where whitespaces are not significant... but hard to say.

Comment: It belongs to the second one `if (y > 0)` if you want it to belong to the first one then you need to close the second if. Without knowing the language though it's hard to tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentations is what is throwing you off since you're not using brackets for these one liner if statements. If you add the brackets back, you will clearly see how the if statement is formed:

```
if (x > 0){
     if (y > 0){
         System.out.println("x > 0 and y > 0");
     }else if ( y< 0){
         System.out.println("x < 0 and z > 0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need the brackets for your code to run properly, but it's better style and the convention to include them. This make's your code easier to read and understand.

@d_ominic has already provided the clean code!